# To - meaning in the sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

> Is there no end **to** this madness?

I think to mean **of** here ,can I use **of** instead?

Comment: While the meaning of "to" here is roughly the same as "of", using "of" would be highly unnatural, arguably bad grammar. I'd give a full answer if I could explain why "*the end **of** this madness*" is natural, but "*no end **of** this madness*" is not.

Comment: ["end **to** this madness" is so much more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=end+*+this+madness&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) than "end *of* this madness" that anything else sounds wrong.  I think it may not be productive to ask "what is the meaning of this preposition", because the use of prepositions is so idiomatic.

Comment: idiomatic expression: the end to some [situation].

Comment: You'll be in no end of trouble if you don't put an end to this madness.

Comment: "[No end of X](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/no-end-of)" is also very common but means loosely "a lot of X" not literally that there is no finish.

Comment: It’s an idiom. It has to be *to*. “No end of trouble (Michael Harvey’s example) is a different idiom. “Is there no end to this madness?” is similar to, “There’s no sense to this message.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sentence "Is there no end to this madness?", the word "to" is used to express the idea of a limit or boundary. It means that the speaker is questioning whether there is any limit to the madness they are experiencing.

You cannot replace "to" with "of" in this sentence because "of" expresses possession, indicating that something belongs to or is associated with something else. Using "of" would completely change the meaning of the sentence.